# Angular multi select tree does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, bower

I used with my project this plugin [angular-multi-select-tree in github](https://github.com/a5hik/angular-multi-select-tree).
This is the way I included it to my project:

1. installed from bower `bower install angular-multi-select-tree -save`
   after this I got string in bower.json :

   "angular-multi-select-tree":"*"
2. And add to index.js "multi-select-tree"

   angular.module('xyzApp', ['multi-select-tree', '....']);

After run "Gulp serve" webpage doesn't work, i saw this error in console

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module multi-select-tree due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'multi-select-tree' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

How can i fix this error? Or which plugin that can be used? necessary functionality:

1. Dropdown list
2. search drop-down list
3. multi select
4. grouping
   Example:
   [image]

Comment: so I included js files to index.htm, but get the same error

Comment: Have you added these scripts
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/angular-multi-select-tree-0.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/angular-multi-select-tree-0.1.0.tpl.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/angular-multi-select-tree-0.1.0.css">`

Comment: What does your app.js look like?

Comment: The error is because the library is not included, the notes in the github lib project is just a reference you need to fix the paths of your dependencies for your project, it depends on your structure and setup. If your `index.html` is in the root folder as well as your `bower_components` the fixed path will be like `"bower_components/angular-multi-select-tree/dist/angular-multi-select-tree-0.1.0.js"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try the isteven-multiselect here is the link;
https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select